# Widening one of the symbols in the overlap of symbols

Tags: symbols

The problem that I am having is that I want to make the intersection and subset signs more distinguished and I think that to make this happen I need to extend the subset legs (facing right) longer. I can't figure out how to do this. I tried `\bigcap`, but I am not aware of `\bigsubset` symbols. Even if there was a `\bigsubset` then the whole thing would just be a bit too big.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\superimpose}[2]{%
  {\ooalign{$#1\@firstoftwo#2$\cr\hfil$#1\@secondoftwo#2$\hfil\cr}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\subsetintersection}{\mathpalette\superimpose{{\subset}{\cap}}}
$\subsetintersection$
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: It is not clear to me, how the result should look like. Can you make a drawing or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\subcap{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\kern.7pt\stackinset{c}{-.3\LMpt}{b}{.8\LMpt}%
  {\scalebox{1.5}[1]{$\SavedStyle\subset$}}%
  {\scalebox{1}[1.5]{$\SavedStyle\cap$}}}\kern .3pt}}
\begin{document}
$    \displaystyle A\subcap B~
        \textstyle A\subcap B~
      \scriptstyle A\subcap B~
\scriptscriptstyle A\subcap B
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip,graphicx}
\newcommand{\longsubset}[1]{%
  #1\subset\joinrel
  \mathrel{\clipbox{{.5\width} 0pt 0pt 0pt}{$#1\subset$}}
}
\newcommand\subsetintersection{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\ssint\relax}% or \mathbin?
}
\newcommand{\ssint}[2]{{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\longsubset{#1}$\cr
    \hidewidth\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\longsubset{#1}$}\hidewidth\cr}
}}


\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\subsetintersection$

$\textstyle\subsetintersection$

$\scriptstyle\subsetintersection$

$\scriptscriptstyle\subsetintersection$
\end{document}
```

[image]